# Why is the gcd so large in an identity related to the $abc$ conjecture?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, elliptic-curves, abc-conjecture

Consider the identity
$$ (x+z)^5+(y-z)^5 = (-3 x + 4 y)^2 (x + y)^3 + (x+y) f(x,y,z) $$

Where $f(x,y,z)=(-8*x^4 + 5*x^3*y + 24*x^2*y^2 - 9*x*y^3 - 15*y^4 + 5*x^3*z - 5*x^2*y*z + 5*x*y^2*z - 5*y^3*z + 10*x^2*z^2 - 10*x*y*z^2 + 10*y^2*z^2 + 10*x*z^3 - 10*y*z^3 + 5*z^4)$.

The curve $C : f(x,y,z)=0 $ is genus 1, have infinitely many rational
and integral points since it is projective.

For a point $(x,y,z)$ on $C$, the identity becomes.

$$ (x+z)^5+(y-z)^5 = (-3 x + 4 y)^2 (x + y)^3 \qquad (1) $$

(1) has infinitely many integer solutions.

Sum of two coprime fifth powers being squarefull infinitely often contradicts the
$abc$ conjecture, so $abc$ implies $\gcd(x+z,y-z) > 1$ (actually
it implies the $\gcd$ is sufficiently large, since clearing a small
gcd will produce abc triples of sufficiently good quality).

$C$ is birationally equivalent to $ E: y^2 = x^3 - \frac{57648010}{243}x - \frac{346032180025}{19683}$ and computing solutions to (1) gives large gcd,
as implied by $abc$. Computing the gcd of the symbolic maps from the
Weiersstras model give $\gcd=7$ (modulo errors).

Other similar identities exist, including genus 0 curves.
The parametrization of genus 0 and $abc$ for polynomials implies
common factor, though the genus 1 case is not clear to me.

> Why the $\gcd$ is sufficiently large?
>
> Is there an unconditional proof that for all similar identies
>   the $\gcd$ will be sufficiently large? ($abc$ implies this).

**Added** Charles asked in a comment about points of infinite order on $C$.

Here are some:

```
 (27, 1, 15)
 (-1343, -1184, 279)
 (-113217, -61531, 74507)
 (-1038297, 1267624, 243888)
 (18490353467, 11046438881, 1513527591)
 (17139398481243, 15697885061884, 4151488981525)
 (-26723833000980177, 15287849768762549, 47286394561187571)
 (-1316887777770612905003, -1407701177079680302604, 837630236024655513348)
```

If $(-u,v)$ **note the minus** is on $E$ a map to (x,y,1) on $C$ is:

```
x,y=(-170318769169205125-1417766490*u^3-531441*u^4+1975193766630*u^2-40040866545750*v+99059869755*v*u+40507614*v*u^2)/(-601680754627470*u-63038098935*u^2+531441*u^4+1748578671*u^3+135424192071124075), (-2125764*u^4-4017005055*u^3+4664819321190*u^2-261600328098900*u-279987440048888425-91293175724310*v+243146953035*v*u+60761421*v*u^2)/(-1805042263882410*u-189114296805*u^2+1594323*u^4+5245736013*u^3+406272576213372225)
```

Comment: This seems interesting, but could you clarify? You have shown that C is of genus 1 (birationally, presumably f=0 is quite singular). And that C has a point of infinite order?

Comment: @CharlesMatthews edited the question giving 8 points of infinite order and a map from the Weiersstras model to C.

Comment: I suspect gcd(x+z,y-z)<max(|x+z|,|y-z|)^E for E small enough might be a putative counterexample to abc for integers, though this is extremely unlikely. There were some large abc triples of moderate quality and low merit after clearing the gcd.

Answer (score 8):

There is an "abc theorem for higher genus curves".

Let $a,b,c$ be three sections of a line bundle of degree $d$ on a curve $C$ of genus $g$ with no common zeroes such that $a+b=c$. Then the number of zeroes of $abc$  is at least $d+2-2g$.

Proof: Let $f = -a/b$ be a map $C \to \mathbb P^1$ of degree $d$. By Riemann-Hurwitz, the total ramification degree is at most $2d+2g-2$. But the total ramification is at least the ramification over the points $0$, $1$, and $\infty$, which is equal to $3d$ minus the number of zeroes of $abc$.

We conclude that if $x'$, $y'$, and $z'$, the pullback of $x+z$, $y-z$, $-3x+4y$ to $E$ are three sections such that $x'^5 + y'^5= z'^2 (x'+y')^3$, then $x'$ and $y'$ cannot be relatively prime (and if we try harder, we can compute how many factors they must share). This is vindicated by the fact that $(x',y',z')=(0,0,1)$ or $(x,y,z)=(-1,1,1)$ is a point on the curve, and is in fact the singular point, so its preimage on $E$ has large degree.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't appear to be _unconditional_ as the second question asks?

Comment: It is, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't understand algebraic geometry, but I fail to see why gcd(x',y') should be large. Would you please try non-rigorous down to earth explanation? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect gcd(x',y')<max(|x'|,|y'|)^E for E small enough might be a putative counterexample to abc for integers, do you have opinion about this?

Comment: What's going on is that the two functions have a common factor in some other embedding of the elliptic curve into projective space. Given enough effort, we could actually compute this embedding and find a common factor. As the point on the curve goes to infinity, the size of the common factor must grow. We can make this precise using heights, and I believe we can show using heights that one never gets a counterexample to abc.

Comment: We can tell that they have a common factor in some embedding because they have common zeroes on the elliptic curve. Those zeroes are exactly the points on $E$ that map to the singular point $(-1,1,1)$. Their existence, in the general case, is guaranteed by a generalization of the argument that proves the Mason-Stothers theorem / abc for polynomials.

Comment: Historical remark: Mason and Stothers stated their result for arbitrary curves, not just $\mathbb{P}^1$. It is later expository accounts that consider just polynomials.

Comment: Thank you! I suppose your argument (with additional effort) works for all higher degree identities involving genus 1 curves? Does it work for surfaces, e.g. if $f=0$ were a surface which gives an abc identity?

Comment: Yes to the first. Not sure about the second. The notion of degree becomes much more subtle there, and the zero sets of $a,b,c$ can overlap in more than one way.

Comment: Does your argument work for integral points on affine curves? Set f(x,y)=x^2+xy-y^2-1, the solutions are consecutive fibonacci numbers?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this question. I think you can certainly guarantee that if this sort of identity holds, all but finitely many have a common prime factor. To get the size of that prime factor I think you can use the basic number theory of heights, but I am not an expert on that. Are you sure the solutions are consecutive Fibonacci numbers? Does that have anything to do with abc?

Comment: Asked about genus 0 giving more details including relations to fibonacci numbers:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138580/integral-points-on-genus-0-curves-related-to-polynomial-identities. By induction it is easy to show that integral points on $x^2+xy -y^2+1=0$ are consecutive fibonacci numbers $(F_{2n},F_{2n+1})$.

Comment: btw, $abc$ implies something stronger than just large gcd, I gave an answer. $abc$ implies sufficiently large squarefree part of the rhs, which is not explained by the size of the gcd only.

Comment: you answer about curves. what happens in higher dimension?

Comment: @joro let me first answer your earlier question. $abc$ is not really stronger than large gcd, because abc requires as a hypothesis that the numbers are relatively prime. If you allow common factors the radical can be small, e.g. $2^n + 2^n = 2^{n+1}$. For higher dimensions, it should work the same for every class of varieties that are conjectured to have infinitely many rational points. In particular, for rationally connected varieties, you can reduce to the curve case, and for varieties with trivial canonical bundle, you can use the canonical bundle.

Comment: What do your arguments say about the generalization known as the n-conjecture: $a_1+a_2+...a_n=0$. We have polynomial parametrization with quality $2n-5$.

Answer (score 2):

The big gcd can be explained as follows: Upon replacing $x$ with $x-z$ and $y$ with $y+z$, we obtain the slightly more convenient equation
\begin{equation*}
x^5+y^5=(-3x+4y+7z)^2(x+y)^3.
\end{equation*}

On the other hand, we have the identity
\begin{equation*}
x^5+y^5=(x^2 - 3xy + 6y^2)(x+y)^3-5y^3(y+x)(y+2x),
\end{equation*}
so if $(x,y,z)$ is a point on the curve, then $(x+y)^3$ divides $5y^3(y+x)(y+2x)$, hence

\begin{equation*}
(x+y)^2\text{ divides }5y^3(y+2x).
\end{equation*}

By homogeneity we may assume that $\text{gcd}(x,y,z)=1$. Set $d=\text{gcd}(x,y)>0$. Now $(x+y)/d$ is relatively prime to $y/d$ and $(y+2x)/d$. So the previous divisibility yields that $(\frac{x+y}{d})^2$ divides $5d^2$. In particular
\begin{equation*}
d\ge \frac{\lvert x+y\rvert^{1/2}}{5^{1/4}}.
\end{equation*}
I believe that a finer kind of this reasoning can improve the lower bound for $d$.

Comment: $(x+y)^2\text{ divides }5y^3(y+2x)$ certainly doesn't imply gcd(x,y) > 1. There are a lot of counterexamples found by fast bruteforce search. Especially when |x+y|=1.

Comment: @joro: I didn't say that $gcd(x,y)>1$. All what I say is that $gcd(x,y)$ grows in terms of $\lvert x+y\rvert$. Actually, for any fixed $x+y$, that is setting $y=a-x$ for a fixed integer $a$. you get an elliptic curve in $x$ and $z$, which then has only finitely many integral points.

Comment: I see. It is still not entirely clear how big |x+y| is. In your example with $y=a-x$ there are infinitely many choices for $a$, so either the curves are birationally equivalent or still $x,z$ can't be sufficiently larger than $a$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The situation appears more complicated.

$abc$ implies something stronger than just large gcd.

The identities are of the form
$$ a^5 + b^5 = c^2 d^3$$

Set $g^5 = \gcd(a^5,b^5)$. If $g^2 || c^2, g^3 || d^3$
we still will have sum of two fifth powers being squarefull,
which contradicts $abc$.

So abc implies sufficiently large squarefree part of $c^2 d^3$
after clearing the gcd.

Experimentally, $|7^3 d^3|=g^6$, which gives identities of the form

$$ a'^5 + b'^5 = c'^2 d' \qquad (1)$$

(1) gives $abc$ triples of barely good quality.

Comment: You seek an explanation for $|7^3d^3|=|g^6|$. I believe I can provide one. Recall that $d=a+b$, and that this is our equation. $a^5+b^5=c^2(a+b)^3$. The equation for a singular form of the elliptic curve is gotten by dividing both sides by $(a+b)$. The singular point is $a=b=0$, $c=1$. It has two inverse images on the elliptic curve, and the order of vanishing of $a$ and $b$ at those images is $1$, while the order of vanishing of $a+b$ is $2$. Since $g$ comes from these points, we expect that $g^2$ divides $d$, which implies the empirical result.

Comment: Mathematically, note that $(a+b)^4+5(a-b)^4 +10 (a+b)^2(a-b)^2 = c^2 (a+b)^2$, hence $(a+b)^2$ divides $(a-b)^4$ (on the curve), hence $(a+b)$ divides $(a-b)^2$ mathematically. We conclude that $d$ divides $4g^2$.