# Integral points on genus 0 curves related to polynomial identities

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Define the polynomial $f(x, y)$ by

$$(x+1)^5+(y+1)^5 = (2x + 6y) ( -x +y )^4 + f(x,y).$$

The curve $C : f(x,y)=0$ has genus 0 and has infinitely many rational
points.
I don't know if it has infinitely many integral points: suppose not.
For integral points on $C$ the identity is:

$$(x+1)^5+(y+1)^5 = (2x + 6y) ( -x +y )^4. \qquad (1)$$

Infinitely many solutions on $C$ with $\gcd(x+1,y+1)=1$
contradict $abc$, so $abc$ implies either finitely many integral
solutions, or sufficiently large $\gcd(x+1,y+1)$ (clearing a small
gcd will still give abc triples of sufficiently good quality).

The integral points might be growing exponentially, so abc for
polynomials doesn't appear to apply.

> Q1 Is there a finite extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ where $C$ has infinitely
> many integral points? How do I find integral points there?

> Q2 Is there a similar identity where $f$ is divisible by a quadratic
> with infinitely many integral points?

I tried to solve Q2 by equating coefficients, but couldn't solve the
system.

Other similar identities exist.

If $f$ is divisible by $g= x^2+xy -y^2+1$, integral points
on $g$ are consecutive fibonacci numbers $(F_{2n},F_{2n+1})$.
If the lhs is still a sum of powers of linear polynomials, it appears
unlikely to me that the common factor will always be large, so probably
such an identity doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

As to Q1: Your curve has $5$ complex points at infinity, so by Siegel's theorem, for the ring of integers $R$ of any number field there are only finitely many $R$-points.

Comment: Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_theorem_on_integral_points) Siegel's theorem that you are using (another source is [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Siegel_theorem))? I am asking because its statement is given only for genus $>0$, whereas the OP claims that his curve has genus $0$.

Comment: @AlexM.   Unfortunately, both sources you link to miss the genus $0$ case, which itself is interesting and highly nontrivial. If there are sufficiently many rational points on the curve, then this curve has a rational parameterization over the rationals. So the problem essentially reduces to the following: What can we say about a rational function which assumes integer values for infinitely many rational arguments? Siegel proved the necessary condition that this function has at most two poles ...

Comment: ... Note that indeed this function need not be a polynomial. Take for instance $1/(x^2-2)$. Then its values are integers at $u/v$ where $u,v$ satisfy the Pell equation $u^2-2v^2=1$. These things are handled in Lang's *Diophantine Geometry*, Chapt. VII, Section 4 (Curves of genus $0$), and probably in his newer edition *Fundamentals of diophantine geometry* too.