# Is it unconditionally known that abc conjecture can't fail on a variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, abc-conjecture

Background:  [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138375/why-is-the-gcd-so-large-in-an-identity-related-to-the-abc-conjecture) gives the identity:

$$(x+z)^5+(y-z)^5 = (-3 x + 4 y)^2 (x + y)^3 + (x+y) f(x,y,z)$$

The curve $C : f(x,y,z)=0$ is genus 1, have infinitely many rational and integral points since it is projective.

abc implies $\gcd(x+y,y-z)$ is very large, spoiling the sum of two coprime fifth powers
being powerful infinitely often.

Consider identity of the form:

$$ a(x_1,\ldots x_i) + b(x_1,\ldots x_i) - c(x_1,\ldots x_i)=f(x_1,\ldots x_i) g(x_1,\ldots x_i) $$

Assume that $f(x_i)=0$ has infinitely many integral points and
the the radical of $a(x_i) b(x_i) c(x_i)$ is small
(because the degree of the radical is small)
and $\gcd(a(x_i),b(x_i))$ is bounded when $f(x_i)=0$ at integers.

If the above happens, it will be counterexample to abc.

> Is this variety attack on abc conjecture unconditionally known to fail?

If $f(x_i)=0$ is genus 0 curve, the parametrization of the curve
is known to satisfy the abc theorem for polynomials and this
appear to suggest $f(x_i)=0$ must be genus 1 curve or of dimension
greater than one.